# Grafana PromQL: How do I get a Line graph of API Request Count?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

How do I get the actual count of the number of requests? and then have the curve return to 0 when there are no requests?

My current methods are either producing a cumulative sum or giving me a rate of requests per time interval.

The chosen type of graph is the time series.

The source of the data is AWS prometheus.

I have tried using this promQL query:

`api_request_count{}`

However; the curve doesn't return to zero when 0 requests have been made, see image below:

[image: result of using api_request_count{}]

I have tried using the a rate query like such:
`rate(api_request_count{}[$__rate_interval])`

But this gives me the rate at a given interval, see below:

[image: result of using rate(api_request_count{}[$__rate_interval])]

Comment: In this case, you probably need query `increase(api_request_count{}[$__rate_interval])`. Please read about [counters](https://www.robustperception.io/how-does-a-prometheus-counter-work/) to gain some understanding what's going on.

Comment: Also, be advised that `increase` not always returns integer values, even if you expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with Prometheus `increase()` data interpolation mentioned [here](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/3746).

My walkaround was to use `rate()` function with `$__rate_interval` as argument and multiply result by the interval(`$__interval_ms / 1000`)

```
(sum(rate(http_server_duration_milliseconds_count{http_route=~"${Route}", http_method=~"${Method}"}[$__rate_interval])) by (http_route, http_method)) * $__interval_ms / 1000
```

for example:

1. you are scraping data every 60 sec
2. `$__rate_interval` is ["guaranteed to be at least four times the scrape interval"](https://grafana.com/blog/2020/09/28/new-in-grafana-7.2-__rate_interval-for-prometheus-rate-queries-that-just-work/) (so it's 4min)
3. We had 10 requests in (almost) one point in time, so the metrics shows change by 10 (from 1 to 11): [image][image] (query: `http_server_duration_milliseconds_count{http_route="/actuator/health", http_method=~"GET"}`)
4. rate query shows average rate in 3 points in time[image](query: `rate(http_server_duration_milliseconds_count{http_route="/actuator/health", http_method=~"GET"}[$__rate_interval])`)
5. you multiply the results by `$__interval_ms / 1000` and you receive number total number of requests (3 point with value of 3,33 requests)[image] (query: `rate(http_server_duration_milliseconds_count{http_route="/actuator/health", http_method=~"GET"}[$__rate_interval]) * $__interval_ms / 1000`)

I recommend using OpenTelemetry standards for Http metrics:
https://opentelemetry.io/docs/specs/otel/metrics/semantic_conventions/http-metrics/

If you decide to go with the standard, you can use predefined [HTTP Dashboard](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/18860-http-metrics-opentelemetry/) prepared by me 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just use [increase()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#increase) over [counter metric type](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#counter):

```
increase(api_request_count[$__rate_interval])
```

This query should return the number of API requests during the previous  [$__rate__interval](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/prometheus/template-variables/#use-__rate_interval) ending at the current point on the graph. If the counter doesn't change during the previous interval, then the graph contains zero value at that point.

Note that Prometheus may return unexpected results from `increase()` function because of the following issues described [here](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/3746):

- it may return non-integer results from integer counters because of extrapolation
- it skips counter increase between the last [raw sample](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#raw-sample) just before the `$__rate_interval` and the first raw sample inside the `$__rate_interval`

Prometheus developers are aware of these issues and are going to fix them eventually. See [this design doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1y2Mp041_2v0blnKnZk7keCnJZICeK2YWUQuXH_m4DVc/edit). In the mean time you can use [an alternative Prometheus-like solution](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics) I work on, which is free from these issues.