# How to use selected interval as range to visualize data for time series graph in prometheus query

Tags: prometheus, grafana, grafana-variable

I want to use interval variable inside the prometheus query, that works as range for visualization of time series graph

I have tried to use the interval by using  $interval but  getting some errors, please help me by providing and example query

Comment: FYI, getting some errors is not useful. Best approach in case of error is to post your exact query and error you are getting (**as text!**)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In Grafana, name of the `interval` variable is `$__interval`, with 2 underscores. [Source](https://grafana.com/blog/2020/09/28/new-in-grafana-7.2-__rate_interval-for-prometheus-rate-queries-that-just-work/)

Make sure, you are using `$__rate_interval` variable for rate(or rate related)
queries.

Example usage:
`rate(http_server_duration_milliseconds_count{service_name=~"${service}"}[$__rate_interval])`

See also problems with interpolation described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77038284/grafana-promql-how-do-i-get-a-line-graph-of-api-request-count/77045329#77045329)